# Not able to fix object 'dataset' not found in R

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function which is passing fit linear model to ncvTest() .

```
runFun <- function(var, dataset){
  model <- lm(formula(var),  data = dataset) # linear fit model
  ncvOut<- ncvTest(model)
  return(ncvOut)
}

runFun(SALES~Time,FOCData)
```

But it is throwing below error :

```
Error in eval(data, envir = environment(formula(model))) : 
  object 'dataset' not found
```

Can someone please help me in fixing this ?

Answer (score 3):

1. first make sure you set correct working directory.
2. have you made dataset before? it cannot exist before you create it
3. if you don't have the dataset before, then read the data to your dataset variable
   for example:

```html
dataset<-read.table('data.txt',header = T)
```

4. try if it works

remember the R function is:

```
myfunction <- function(arg1, arg2, ... ){
statements
return(object)
}
```

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question.

Comment: I mean you need to have a dataset before you can use it

Comment: I am passing data set as an input to the function runFun. FOCData is a data set .

Comment: In addition, if i use summary function instead of ncvTest, the function is running perfectly fine.                                                                       
 runFun <- function(var, dataset){
  model <- lm(formula(var),  data = dataset)
  sumry<- summary(model)
  return(sumry)
}

runFun(SALES~Time,FOCData)